# Error compling React Native in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

when I write this command on the terminal (`react-native run-android`) it returns me error and I can't understand why. I'm trying to develop an app with react-native but when I import the android folder on android studio I see some errors but react-native files are downloaded.
My code is:

```
package com.project;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage()
      );
    }

   @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

The compiler is outputting me with `Can't resolve symbol 'ReactApplication' and 'ReactNativeHost'`.

Comment: if react-native is indeed in your app/build.gradle, perhaps node module isn't installed ? have you run `npm install` from your project root ?

Comment: I tried npm install but the problem is here anyway